# C++/.net (Framework 2.0) MS SQL db windows authentication with user name and password

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, windows, winapi

I am using following set of API(C++) to validate a windows user name and password (domain account) with MS SQL db:

1. LogonUser
2. CreateEnvironmentBlock
3. ImpersonateLoggedOnUser
4. SQLDriverConnect

It works just fine but problem occurs when a service account (domain account but you cant log-in in windows using it) is used to for validation. it fails in the LogonUser API.

Is there any way in C++ or .net (Framework 2.0) to validate a domain account with MS SQL db without using impersonation mechanism?

Thanks,

Rahul

Comment: if you grant the service account permission to LogonLocal temporarily, does it work then?

Comment: @Paul it's not allowed to modify the permissions.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what you are trying to do. Have you got a Desktop Application trying to run as a Service? Are you running a service and attempting to Logon a different User.

Comment: @paul I am working on a desktop application which has a page to provide the SQL credentials. once user provides the credentials then I validate those using the set of API I mentioned in my question. In one scenario user has provided service user credentials and I am getting issue there. Service user account has rights on SQL but you can not login windows using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe instead of using `LogonUser`, maybe you could try using [LogonUserEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it allows you to specify the type of logon you are requesting. With a *dwLogonType* = **LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE**

Comment: Thanks paul. I used dwLogonType as **LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT** it worked.